# OSX: Can NOT ping to the network interface of NAS

Tags: macos, networking, nas, ping

Suddenly, I can NOT access NAS using Finder so I tried to do ping to the network interface of NAS with straight cable which is connected to the box directly. But, I could NOT ping to the interface. What I found is the IP address has changed without my hands. I tried to find the issue is as follows;

Could you tell me how to fix it?

What I did is as follows;

1. Disabled all Firewall
2. Create new network interface with IP
   address.

But no luck.

It seems be the IP address has changed without my hands.

Condition:

1. Can ping to my local address
2. Can NOT ping to the IP address of NAS from my Mac
3. Can find ARP packet from the interface of NAS has IP address(Original IP address was 192.168.150.54 but the IP address is seems be 192.168.11.150)
   [image]
4. Routing table
   [image]

Environment:

1. Direct connection with my straight cable which I could use it
   before. Direct connection mean is without Hub.
2. Disabled Firewall of Mac and Norton.

Rebooted my Mac but no luck. I will create new Id to confirm soon. but It won't be worked.

Possibilities:
Cable detection is fixed as straight?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Were you previously connecting to your NAS via a router, or using the direct connection? Were you connecting via host name or IP address? What happens if you try connecting to smb://192.168.11.150 ?

Comment: @James I will try this and the connectivity is direct without HUB(home use)

Comment: I could not access using smb.